# Usage of property() contruct in python

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying a small database manager with validation in python and I'm facing this problem:

If I use @property like this:

```
class Attribute (object):
    def __init__ (self, value=None):
        self._value = value
    @property
    def value (self):
        return self._value
    @value.setter
    def value (self, value):
        if isinstance(value,int):
            self._value = value
        else:
            self._value = None

class A (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.a = Attribute()

ia = A()
```

Then I can access the validated value as `ia.a.value` and set it validated as `int` with `ia.a.value=<some int>`. But I want it to be accessed by `ia.a` (without the `value`)

I've tried most of the variants I'm capable of think about for the following (autogenerated by Sublime Text 2) code:

```
def attribute ():
    def fget (self):
        return self._value
    def fset (self, value):
        if isinstance(value,int):
            self._value = value
        else:
            self._value = None
    return locals()

class A (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.a = property(**attribute())

ia = A()
```

When I do `print(type(ia.a))` it outputs something like "`<property object at 0x7ffa84a8a7e0>`", but as soon as I change the value with `ia.a=3`, for example, it becames `int`. In fact, the setter is not being called and the assignment is as usual (I can assign a string to the property, for example).

What I want to do is some dynamic class setup by passing a parameter to the `attribute` function with the name of every user defined class attribute in order to define instance attributes using `getattr`, `setattr` and `delattr` in that function.

How can I do that? What's the correct usage of the `parameter` constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that property objects should be set on `class` (as class attributes), not on the instance , this is why the setter/getter is never called for your property.

For your case, you can simply do -

```
class A:
    a = property(**attribute())
```

Comment: I've been working arround with this for several hours and I'm unable to get why this is this way. Only static descriptors are allowed? How did you use a descriptor in an instance. I know it's posible to use the instance parameter in `__get__` and `__set__` methods, but I'm trying to put some other (instance, not static) data in adition to the value of the instance variable.